# Function returns strings but not when stored in variable

Tags: php, string, function, oop

I have a strange problem with a function i wrote. When returning an hardcoded string like "Hello" it returns this value, but when i store this value in a variable it doesn't return anything.

Also when i don't store it in a variable and try to return it nothing gets returned.

Below is my code. Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
 public function getPath($pageID = null) {
    if($pageID == null) $pageID = $this->id;

    $data = $this->_db->fetch_array("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '".$pageID."'");

    if(!empty($data)) {
        $this->tempPath[] = $data['basename'];

        if($data['parentID'] != 0) {
            $this->getPath($data['parentID']);
        } else {
            $returnPath = $this->tempPath;
            $this->tempPath = array();
            $returnPath = implode('/', array_reverse($returnPath));
            //This variable holds the value, when echo'ed its the correct value
            echo $returnPath;

            return $returnPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Do you get any errors? Do you show us your real code?

Comment: This is all the code used in the function, it's producing the correct data but when returning nothing gets returned. When i code: return "Hello" it does return "Hello", But it doesn't return any values in variables.

Comment: What is the exact output of: `var_dump($returnPath);` right before the return statement?

Comment: This is the ouput:

string(15) "admin/dashboard"
string(15) "admin/pages/add"
string(11) "admin/pages"

Comment: Is this code in a loop which you don't show us?!

Comment: Code was inside a loop which caused the problem, posted the solution below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote the code to the following and now it's working

```
 public function getPath($pageID = null) {
    if($pageID == null) $pageID = $this->id;

    $data = $this->_db->fetch_array("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '".$pageID."'");

    if(!empty($data)) {
        $this->tempPath[] = $data['basename'];
    }

    return implode('/', $this->tempPath);
}
```

Problem was that the code was in a foreach loop which kept overwriting the correct values and looping till there is no path to return. Thanks for the suggestions.

More code isn't always better :-)